# How do I get each and every item in a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following divs:

```
 <div  id='1'   title='A'  description='B' activity-note='C'  grouped-as='Test'>  </div>
 <div  id='4'   title='Z'  description='Z' activity-note='Z'  grouped-as='Soil Prep'>  </div>
 <div  id='5'   title='Q'  description='Q' activity-note='Q'  grouped-as='Soil Prep'>  </div>
```

I would like to get the values for each of the assigned items in the div.

I have tried using the following (as an example) but I get an error:

```
title=document.getElementById('1').getAttribute("title");
```

Obviously I am confused and so any help and/or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: That line should work. What's the problem?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: get the following in Chrome:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')

Comment: Can you edit this question and post how your JS relates to your HTML (as in, is it placed in the head element?  Elsewhere?).  I have a suspicion it's a race condition issue.  JS is fast and will attempt to access elements before the DOM is actually rendered.

Comment: @JackStein Seems to work OK in Chrome. https://codepen.io/ceejayoz/pen/dyQejoB

Comment: Where is your JS in relation to your elements? This may be a load order issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: The issue was due to how I was generating the <div >  I generated each div in the php code after each <option> I  generated for a drop down list. When I moved  this to be after the </select> as  a concatenated string of all the <div> the issue went away - no more errors.  It was a hunch I pursued after hearing that the way I was getting the data was correct so it must have been how I was generating the <div>   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

> Similarly, an id starting with a digit (E.g., 1234-322-678) or a hyphen followed by a digit (E.g., -123), though valid in HTML, may lead to problems when used in CSS, JavaScript, and Web APIs:

> Such an id is not a valid JavaScript identifier. Elements with IDs become global properties, but you cannot use non-identifier global properties as global variables — 1234 is not a global variable, and you have to use window[1234] instead to get the element with id="1234". This is slightly inconvenient as you have to create the variable with an extra step: const element = window[1234].

Comment: I changed the id to not be numeric - <div  id='activity1'   title='A'  description='B' activity-note='C'  grouped-as='Test'>  </div>   still get the following in Chrome:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')